# Stiff Steering and Suspension

Tags: suspension, steering

Steering and Suspension gets stiff while riding my MTB. I did service the front suspension about 3 months ago (which is not long ago, since i only ride on weekends), but the problem still exists. When i don't ride it and it stands in house, the suspension seems to be working good and steering is not stiff. SR Suntour XCR is the model of my fork

Comment: what do you mean by "_steering_...gets stiff"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Can you include a bit more description of your problem?  What kind of riding are you doing?  Can you clarify how "stiff" it gets?  Is it uniformly stiff through its range of motion?  Does it gradually get stiff or suddenly switch to being stiff after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Hi guys. I ride Cross Country. It gets stiff after about a mile of riding. Steering is hard to turn and suspension is as if it's locked.